# How to map nested JSON to an Object structure with functions?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to map a structure like this:

```
{ 
    "stuff": {
        "onetype": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "othertype": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    }, 
    "otherstuff": {
        "thing": "some value"
     }
}
```

to an object containing 2 arrays of objects (stuff and other stuff). I would like to build a prototype for this JSON object so that I have all my functions available. I would like to be able to do something like this (tree being the parent object). `tree.display()` where the display function will go thought the array one type and call the functions display on the containing objects.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Can somebody point me to an example of how to do this?
Can I use a functions like `$.extend`?

this is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    JSONString = '\
        {"stuff": \
            {"onetype": \
                [{"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},\
                {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}],\
            "othertype": \
                {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}\
            }, \
        "otherstuff": {"thing": "some value" }\
        }';

    function Tree () {
        this.stuff = new StuffObject();
        this.otherstuff;
        this.showValue = function () {
            $("body").append(this.otherstuff.thing);
        }
    }

    function StuffObject () {
        this.onetype = new Array();
        this.othertype = new OthertypeObject();
    }

    function OthertypeObject () {
        this.id = 0;
        this.company = "unspecified";
        this.showCompany = function(){
            console.log(this.company);
        }
    }

    var firstTree = $.extend(true, new Tree, JSON.parse(JSONString));
    console.log(firstTree);
    firstTree.showValue();
    firstTree.stuff.othertype.showCompany();
});
```

Comment: $.extend(new Tree, JSON.parse(plain_JSON));
Tree is a prototype containing fields named stuff and otherstuff, the functions in the prototype are not able to work correctly. console.log(tree.otherstuff.thing) will display value, something function using this value gives me an undefined

Comment: @MaartenArits Show us the code you have, also 'something function using this value gives me an undefined' is not something I can parse. I'm not going to downvote you for that, but please try again.

Comment: @Daedalus, thanks for the comment, i'm new to this. I pasted in some code that i try to map the object to, the first layer workst but it is not yet a deep copy

Answer (score 0):

If you only Want to display some certain field you can Try this it will give the Company name:

```
<script>
    alert("see this");
    JSONString = '\
        {"stuff": \
            {"onetype": \
                [{"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},\
                {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}],\
            "othertype": \
                {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}\
            }, \
        "otherstuff": {"thing": "some value" }\
        }';

    function Tree () {
        this.stuff = new StuffObject();
        this.otherstuff;
        this.showValue = function () {
            $("body").append(this.otherstuff.thing);
        }
    }

    function StuffObject () {
        this.onetype = new Array();
        this.othertype = new OthertypeObject();
    }

    function OthertypeObject () {
        this.id = 0;
        this.company = "unspecified";
        this.showCompany = function(){
            console.log(this.company);
        }
    }

    var firstTree = $.extend(true, new Tree, JSON.parse(JSONString));
   // var x=json_encode(firstTree);
    console.log(firstTree);
    var x = JSON.stringify(firstTree.stuff.othertype.company);
    alert(x);

</script>
```